# Signup user once with lightopenid along with info and then login with database info

Tags: php, lightopenid

I have implemented an Google open-id login - signup system using lightopenid which is working fine, i want to add a functionality which require user to sign up only once to allow access to their info, then i store that info in database for login afterwords.

Once i get their info (identity, name, email), i store them in database to log them in afterwords through same process except to skip user to grant access to their info again and again.

i.e when user has signup and granted access to there info, the next time onwards user dont have to grant access every time to login.

To implement it i am checking their identity in the database when trying to login, if identity exist then login them without asking for info in lightopenid, if identity is not their ask them once for their info to store it in database for later login use.

i can check for their identity in database, but stuck in the part if identity is not their then how to ask for their info since i have not requested for the info in lightopenid when login.

**the code to store info once.(SignUp)**

```
    $openid = new LightOpenID('localhost');
    if(!$openid->mode) {
    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
        $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
        $openid->required = array('namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last', 'contact/email');
        header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    }
} 
if($openid->validate()) {
    require_once('../connect.php');
    $identity = $openid -> identity;
    $info = $openid->getAttributes();
    $username = $info['namePerson/first'].'.'.$info['namePerson/last'];
    $open_id = explode('=', $identity);
    $identity_hash = $open_id[1];
    $email = $info['contact/email'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO user_login (username, identity_hash, email) VALUES ('$username', '$identity_hash', '$email')"; 
    $create_user = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

**the code to check identity.(LogIn)**

```
    if(!$openid->mode) {
    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
        $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
        header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    }
} 
if($openid->validate()) {
    require_once('../connect.php');
    $identity = $openid -> identity;
    $open_id = explode('=', $identity);
    $identity_hash = $open_id[1];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE identity_hash='$identity_hash'";
    $result = mysqli_query($ulconnection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);

    if($result){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $username = $row['username'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $username.'<br />';
    echo $email.'<br />';
    }
    else{
    // how to ask for info here.
    }
}
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this way.

```
    if($result){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $username = $row['username'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo $username.'<br />';
    echo $email.'<br />';
    }
    else{
    header("Location: signup.php?login");   
    }
```

Hope this helps others too.